# Bootstrap V2 vs V3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am looking to use bootstrap for a responsive design.  I would like to know if it's better to go with Bootstrap 3 RC2 or stay with v2.3.2.  Here is a sample page with Bootstrap 3 RC2 : http://lepetshop.ca/aide/responsive/.  I want the page to look great on a smart phone, a tablet, laptop and desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will be working on the site for a while before it's live, my vote would be to go with Bootstrap 3.

Since the latest version is still in release candidate mode there may still be the odd blip with it, though if your site will be in deveopment for a while this will buy you some time.

I think you'll be able to have your site looking great with either version, but since the grid classes have changed a lot, upgrading from Bootstrap 2 --> Bootstrap 3 won't be automatic. Going straight to the latest version will save you some time down the road and you'll be able to get used to using the new classes for the grid now.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks David, your answer is greatly appreciated and to the point.  I agree :)